# java spring - post request with additional value

Tags: java, html, spring, post, thymeleaf

I have implemented a registration process where you can send user data to the controller via post request.

The post request works fine, however now I want to pass another value (role, Long) from the form to the controller that is not an attribute of the user model.

That part is not working.
Does anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<form action="add_user" method="post" class="form-horizontal" th:object="${user}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" placeholder="Person ID" type="text" name="id" id="id"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input th:field="*{password}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <select th:field="${role}" class="form-control" id="role">
                                <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                <option value="2" >User</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String showUsers(Model model) 
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("role", new Long(2));
        return "users";
}
```

And:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, long role) {
    if (user != null) {
        System.out.println(role);
        userService.save(user);
    }
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`th:field="${role}"` means name of field in the model object, not its value. You probably want to write `th:value="${role}"` instead of this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove `th:field="${role}"`?

Comment: Yes
           
                                <select th:value="${role}" class="form-control" id="role">
                                    <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                    <option value="2" >User</option>
                                </select>

Comment: In this case `name="role"` is needed as well, as "name" attribute is used for form posting

Comment: i even tried a normal input type=text to see if it has anything to do with the select option